# cross database ownership chaining - implementation dangers?

Tags: sql-server-2008

We have decided to implement cross database ownership chaining in our SQL Server 2008 environment, which is a replication of the application database and a reporting database.  The reporting db is views pointing to the (replicated) app db.  By enabling this, we can grant access to read the views but not the underlying tables.

My question is we will be implementing this in production - what are our risks?  I need to know how sophisticated our back-out plan needs to be... thanks!

Answer (score 3):

if you are responsible for both data bases, this seem to be good enough solution. But in case there are different owners in both data bases, then owner of one data base can access objects of other database without having rights to do that.

For example, im owner of db1, owning shema dbo. You are owner of db2, owning shema dbo. i am user of db1, but do not have any rights to access any dbo objects in your db. If i write procedure in my database db2, witch selects data from dbo.SomeTable, then because of ownership chain there is now check if i can access dbo.SomeTable in db2.

Great article on this subject can be found [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html).

Comment: +1 for referencing Erland's article, which is another great source from the master.